# python's inspect.getfile returns "<string>"

Tags: python, python-inspect

Consider this code:

```
from sqlalchemy import exists
import inspect

print(inspect.getfile(exists))
# Effectively calls:
print(exists.__code__.co_filename)
```

On 2 systems I've tested it on it prints:

```
<string>
<string>
```

What does it mean? Could anything be done to get a proper filepath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<string>` means that the function was defined dynamically by executing a string, rather than being defined in the text of a file. You can see this if you do:

```
exec('def foo(): return 1')
print(inspect.getfile(foo))
```

I'm not sure why sqlAlchemy needs to define `exists()` this way. But I don't think there's any way to get the source file that does it.